# python global variable 0MQ

Tags: python

How can I share a socket variable in two python scripts

file that create socket bindings 'zmq_settings.py'

```
import zmq
def create_socket_connection():

    zmq_port = "XXX"
    context = zmq.Context()
    global zmq_socket
    zmq_socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    zmq_socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % zmq_port)

def client_send_json(send_json):
    return zmq_socket.send_json(send_json)
```

Sever file that accept requests from the client 'server.py'

```
import zmq_settings

create_socket_connection()

while True:
    try:
        print "\n************\t****************"
        print "[radio_server]\t Waiting..."
        incoming_json = zmq_settings.client_recv_json()  # Wait for next    request from client
        print "Received request: ", incoming_json
        zmq_settings.client_send_json(json_success)
```

There is another file that also needs to use socket variable to send to the same client 'event_listener.py'

```
import zmq_settings

if CONDITION
    send_event_to_client(event_json)
else:
    print "jfjd"
```

Using global keyword inside function doesn't work and also initialization"zmq_settings = None' above the function "create_socket_connection" gives error

Comment: 'There is another file'. Do you run *two* programs?

Comment: Yeah, two programs , one program listens on a particular port and sends data to the client, the other program also needs to send data to the same client using the same socket connection.

Comment: That is not possible. Two programs can't share the same 0MQ socket.